# Show that $F(A)=S$ and that the function is bijective.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, continuity, smooth-functions

Define
$$\tag{1}
\begin{equation}
S:=\{(x, y, z) \in A \times \mathbb{R} \mid z=h(x, y)\},
\end{equation}
$$
where $A = \begin{equation}
\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \times\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{equation}$ and $h(x,y):=\log(\frac{\cos y}{\cos x})$.
Further, define $F : A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$\tag{2}
F(x,y)=(x,y,h(x,y)).
$$
Now, I am supposed to show that $F(A)=S$ and that the smooth map $F$ is bijective with continuous inverse
$$\tag{3}
\begin{equation}
F^{-1}(x, y, z)=(x, y)
\end{equation}.
$$
To show that $F(A)=S$, I need to show that $\forall s\in S\exists (x,y)\in A$ such that $F(x,y)=S$. To show that it is a bijection, I need to show that $(x,y)$ in unique.
So pick some $(x,y,z)\in S$. Then
$$\tag{4}
F(x,y)=(x,y,h(x,y))=(x,y,z)
$$
Hence, $F(A)=S$. It also shows that $(x,y)$ is unique, because if $(x',y')\ne (x,y)$, then $(x,y,z)\ne(x',y',z')$. Finally, it also shows that eq. $(3)$ holds. Since any smooth function is continuous, and the inverse of a continuous is continuous, we know that $F^{-1}$ in eq. $(3)$ is continuous.

Did I misunderstand something, or is eq. $(4)$ really sufficient to solve the given problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $S$ is actually known as the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of $h$.
The map $F$ simply maps the input of $h$ to the corresponding point on the graph of $h$.
If $h$ is bijective and smooth, then $F$ is of course bijective and smooth.
The formal proof of this is similar to what you wrote,
basically nothing to prove.